# Parent field returns error: 'Must match pattern ^projects/[^/]+/models/[^/]+$'

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am new to GCP and am trying to learn how to use the API Explorer so that I can use GCP features on my website. I am stuck with the following error and am not sure what the solution is. Seems like it could be just a syntax mistake on my part...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is a regular expression, not a literal string. Based on your example, you probably mean to use the value:

```
projects/gs-demo-v1/models/census
```